# Seeing a lot of "stream error: stream ID 1221; PROTOCOL_ERROR" since 23rd March from a single Linode DC

Tags: go, google-bigquery

We've had a lot of these errors from only one of our DCs - running the same code as others globally.

For example:

> 2017/03/31 13:22:03 Error sending request to BigQuery (attempt 1 of 3): Post https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/coull-delta/datasets/demand/tables/table_name/insertAll?alt=json: stream error: stream ID 1221; PROTOCOL_ERROR

It uses the Big Query Go package from google - https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api

Anyone got any ideas? Seen this before? As I said, exactly the same code running in other places with no issue.